# java8 lambda: convert a String of 0's and 1's to basic array of booleans

Tags: java, arrays, string, lambda, boolean

let's say I have a String of 0's and 1's, and I want to convert it to an array of booleans. How do I do it?

This is my take:

```
String str = "101010"
boolean bit[] = str.char().map(c -> (c == '1' ? true : false)).toArray();
```

please help.

Comment: Alright, so what's wrong with your take? What problem is it giving you (yes, I can guess, but it's up to you to write a good question)

Answer (score 3):

```
Boolean[] bools = str.chars().mapToObj((c) -> (char)c == '1').toArray(Boolean[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the mapToObj Method:

```
Boolean[] bools = str.chars().mapToObj((c) -> c == '1').toArray(Boolean[]::new);
```

Comment: This needs to be `Boolean` and not the primitive type. Why did you remove the edits that were helping your answer become correct.

Comment: When I use `IntFunction<boolean[]> func = boolean[]::new;` and then `.toArray(func)`, what I did when I first tested it, it works. Also using a explicit cast works: `.toArray((IntFunction<boolean[]>) boolean[]::new)`

Comment: This solution yields array of Boolean false.

Comment: Yes, I was just focused on the fact that the chars-Method returns a Stream of Integer and not of Characters that I checked for the Integer value 1.
Also the use of `IntFunction<boolean[]>` compiles just fine, but causes the JVM to show up a Errormessage when executed. Should this be reported to Oracle?

Comment: `Boolean[] bools = str.chars().mapToObj((c) -> c == 49).toArray(Boolean[]::new);`