# How to convert a string to a boolean[] array using Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

The `*` character converts to true, everything else to false.

This answer shows how to convert to Boolean[], but I seek to convert to an array of scalar booleans.

[java8 lambda: convert a String of 0's and 1's to basic array of booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44469158/java8-lambda-convert-a-string-of-0s-and-1s-to-basic-array-of-booleans)

Comment: do you want to use lambdas?

Comment: This is actually going to be highly difficult.  The best solution I can think of is `collectingAndThen(toList(), boxedBooleanListToArray)` or the like.

Comment: @travisjayday yes

Comment: @LouisWasserman can you be more specific?

Comment: Sure: there's not going to be a better way than converting to a `Boolean[]` or a `List<Boolean>` and then converting that to a primitive `boolean[]`, and you'll have to write that part yourself (or get it from a third-party library).

Comment: Converting to an array of `boolean` primitive type is a waste of resources. It's much better to use a `BitSet`. Do you need a `boolean[]` for any special reason?

Comment: Do you think a JVM would optimize an array of boolean primitives into some sort of a bitmask-like structure?

Comment: It would be allowed to do so, but in case of the widespread Hotspot JVM, no, it doesn’t.

Answer (score 7):

If the requirements are simply to convert to the described boolean array and to use streams, you can do it like this:

```
boolean[] result = new boolean[string.length()];
IntStream.range(0, string.length()).forEach(n -> result[n] = (string.charAt(n)=='*'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a `BitSet` instead, which is the more efficient storage structure

```
BitSet bs = IntStream.range(0, string.length())
                     .filter(i -> string.charAt(i)=='*')
                     .collect(BitSet::new, BitSet::set, BitSet::or);
```

You can test the bits using `bs.get(index)`, which is not worse than `array[index]`.

Note that a `BitSet` also has a `stream()` method which produces an `IntStream` of the indices of `true` value, equivalent to the stream we used for constructing the `BitSet`. So if you can’t get away without an array at some point, you could create it like

```
boolean[] array = new boolean[string.length()];
bs.stream().forEach(i -> array[i]=true);
```

Comment: Holger, I was terribly slow with this question (actually I'm having a SO break), but I had in mind exactly this.